# Why is the login service not called in AngularJS using $http?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to call a service using $http service. On button click, I call service but I am getting an error. How do I call the authentication login service in AngularJS?

Here is my code:

```
$scope.firstrequest = function() {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.username = "tob.mob@bbb%%..test";
    $scope.data.password = "@1234";
    dataa = "username=" +  $scope.data.username + "&" + "password=" +  $scope.data.password;
    console.log('Sign In function called');

    if ($scope.data.username && $scope.data.username != "" && $scope.data.password && $scope.data.password != "") {
        $http({
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            url: "https://fulldemo3-yuj****",
            data: dataa
        }).success(function(result) {
            alert('---')
            //    $scope.loader = true;
            console.log("result:" + JSON.stringify(result));



            $scope.loader = false;
       } 
   }.error(
       function(error) {

           alert('error')

       }));

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forget a closing `)` in your code

replace:

```
}.error(
```

by (just added the `)`):

```
}).error(
```

to solve your problem

UPDATED Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vsAC4c2z0HoIVBMK2fSQ?p=preview